# Input file needs to be edited by the code in tcl

Tags: list, replace, tcl, element

I have a text file that I need to edit once it is input by the user.
I have used the foreach command along with split to split the input file into lines where each line breaks at \n and then I have further broken down each line into words by using split again for each line. 
My objective is to replace one particular word with a new word.
And then I am supposed to replace a particular line with a new one.
How do I do so?

Comment: Please post your code; indicate what you've done, and what's not working.

Comment: YOu'll want to learn about [lsearch](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/lsearch.htm) and [lreplace](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/lreplace.htm). [string map](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M34) will help you too.

Comment: You could just replace with regsub

Comment: Briefly: you construct a _new_ list of all the lines (don't worry; you copy most of the original lines over and its efficient) and then you write the lines out to a file (if desired). Everything would be much clearer if you showed your code…

Comment: @FrobberOfBits,The text file I am taking input from is named deck. I want to replace ivfrz with i-v.

`foreach line [split $deck \n] {
foreach word [split $line] {
if {[lsearch -all $word ivfrz] >= 0} {
string replace $word 0 4 i-v
}
}
}`

Comment: @AbhiritKanti Could you put your full code in the question? It is hard to read code in comments, and if `deck` is the file name, you have to `read` or `gets` its contents instead of directly looping over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need to split the contents of the file at all:

```
set fh [open deck r]
set deck [read -nonewline $fh]
close $fh

regsub -all {\mivfrz\M} $deck {i-v} deck
```

I use the `\m` and `\M` constraints to ensure that I'm only matching a whole word. See http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm#M72

To rewrite your method:

```
foreach line [split $deck \n] {
    set words [split $line]
    foreach index [lsearch -all -exact $words "ivfrz"] {
        lset words $index "i-v"
    }
    lappend new_deck $words
}
```